# Time Difference Excel hh:mm Giving Odd Answer

Tags: excel

I am flabbergasted as to what I am doing wrong as I simply want it to show 39:54 (39 hours, 54 minutes).  I'm guessing it's something obvious but the formulas I've tried either give me 21:36 (?) or 39.9.  39.9 makes sense as it's 39 hours but the .9 is related to 54 minutes being 90% of 60 minutes.

Any help is much appreciated.  Thank you !

[image]

Comment: The difference between those two dates is 1479 hours, not 39 hours (assuming `dd/MM/yyyy` date format).

Comment: @Dai These dates are probably of mm/dd/yy format.

Comment: @Variatus Ah yes - I tried both formats in Linqpad and indeed, it's `2020-01-07 09:55` and `2020-01-09 01:49` with a difference of `39.9` hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

```
=TEXT(M3-L3,"[hh]:mm")
```

Excel stores date/time as days and fractions of a day since `1/1/1900` where that date = 1

`M3-L3` --> the difference in date/time

To format that result as hours:minutes, you use `[hh]:mm`

`hh` rolls over the hours every 24; `[hh]` will display the cumulative hours.

So, when you calculate `(M3-L3) * 24`, you are converting the stored value to hours. But `[hh]:mm` expects the value that you are formatting to be an actual date/time value.  Hence the error.

In your second example, where you show the result of `(m3-l3)*24` is `39.9`; you have converted the time difference to decimal hours.  `39.9` is 39 hours + 0.9 hours which is the same as 39 hours 54 minutes (0.9 * 60 minutes = 54 minutes)

Comment: I can't find any mention of the meaning of square-brackets [in Excel's documentation for `TEXT()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c). Do you know where this is documented?

Comment: @Dai Not offhand, but do an internet search for the numberformatting methods in Excel.

Comment: According to this page; https://exceljet.net/custom-number-formats - square-brackets are used to set conditional formatting - the examples given don't coincide with your answer (which I haven't tested).

Comment: @Dai Yes, that is one use for the square brackets.

Comment: @Dai And if you examine the **entire page** that you reference in your comment, you will find examples of using the square brackets with various time formats.

Comment: Derp. My mistake! In my defense, the square-brackets only appear in a screenshot, not searchable text (I used Ctrl+F  + `[` - so the "Number formats for ELAPSED TIME"  don't appear in my browser's find results).

Answer (score 2):

(Rant: Excel's date and time formatting capabilities are very limited and difficult to work with - I'm sure it was great in comparison to other spreadsheet systems in the mid-1990s, but Microsoft has always been very conservative about updating Excel's core functionality - so even today, in 2020, Excel does not have a built-in formula function equivalent to `DateTime.ParseExact` and it ALWAYS prefers local computer settings which is bloody annoying as my computer is set to `en-GB` (but uses `yyyy-MM-dd` as my date-format override) so it's impossible to easily parse US-formatted date values, argh) - [and there's still no support for consistently parsing ISO 8601 values](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/19448266-support-iso8601-for-all-locales-in-date-time-forma), which is crazy for 2020.

<del>Anyway - given this backstory on Excel's pathetic date and time formatting and parsing functionality, it's no surprise then that Excel doesn't support formatting `hh` as "total hours" - it always renders it in Modulo 24 (or Modulo 12 if you specify `h`)</del>

<sup>(I retract the above statement because Ron's answer of `[hh]:mm` works, but it's still under-documented behaviour as it's not mentioned in [Excel's documentation for `TEXT()` at all](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c))</sup>

Assuming that `L2` and `M2` are being interpreted as Date+Time values correctly (I assume `L2` is `2020-01-07 09:55` and `M2` is `2020-01-09 01:49`- and not `2020-01-07 09:55` and `2020-01-09 01:49` respectively), then try this:

1. Set `N2`'s formula to `= M2 - L2` - this should result in a floating-point Number value that represents the number of days-difference between the two dates.
2. Format it manually in `O2` with this formula

   ```
   = FLOOR( N2 * 24, 1 ) & ":" & ( ( N2 * 24 ) - TRUNC( N2 * 24 ) * 60 )
   ```

### Update:

With my apologies to @RonRosenfeld, [the examples given in the ExcelJet page **do** include a mention of using `\[` and `\]` for formatting Elapsed Time values](https://exceljet.net/custom-number-formats). The example is given as a screenshot which makes it impossible to search for <sub>(it's 2020 and search engines still don't do OCR on images - nor do browsers do Find-in-Page for images either)</sub>. I'll repeat the information in text form so people can grep this answer:

From https://exceljet.net/custom-number-formats

> Elapsed time is a special case and needs special handling. By using square brackets, Excel provides a special way to display elapsed hours, minutes, and seconds. The following screen shows how Excel displays elapsed time based on the value in D5, which represents 1.25 days:
>
> ```
>     A                                 B                     C
>     Description                       Formula               Formatted Value
>     -----------------------------------------------------------------------
> 1   Example elapsed time (days)       =1.25                 1.25
> 2   Elapsed hours (total hours)       =TEXT(B1, "[h]")      30
> 3   Elapsed hours with minutes        =TEXT(B1, "[h]:mm")   30:00
> 4   Elapsed minutes                   =TEXT(B1, "[m]")      1800
> 5   Elapsed minutes with seconds      =TEXT(B1, "[m]:ss")   1800:00
> 6   Elapsed seconds                   =TEXT(B1, "[ss]")     108000
> 7   Elapsed seconds with milliseconds =TEXT(B1, "[ss].00")  108000.00
> ```

I cannot find any authoritative reference in Excel's documentation for the behaviour of `[]` when formatting numbers as durations - so *technically* this could be considered undocumented behaviour. That said, it probably is documented in the offline help files of older versions of Excel, I know a lot of useful documentation was lost when Office moved to all-online help between 2003 and 2013, grrrrrr.

Comment: It used to be well documented online. Now it seems it is only documented online by Microsoft under Excel for MAC; but the codes are the same.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `TEXT` function. Subtract one time from the another and format the cells with a custom format `[h]:mm`

[image]